# Associating a model url with the collection url while making a new model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to make a new model and save it on the server. My problem is that when i do `model.save(obj)`, it throws an error `A "url" property or function must be specified`.

I have already specified a url in the collection and i wish to use that.

My code :

```
 class TestModel extends Backbone.Model

    initialize: ->
      return;

 module.exports = TestModel



 class TestCollection extends Backbone.Collection

    model: TestModel

    url: '/models'

    parse :(response) ->
        return response.data

    addModel : (data)->
        newModel = new TestModel(data)
        newModel.save()
        @add(newModel)

module.exports = new TestCollection()
```

And i am calling the addModel function like this

```
Tests = require 'path/to/test collection'
Tests.addModel(data)
```

This is throwing an error `A "url" property or function must be specified`

If i modify my addModel function to be the following, it works! :

```
addModel : (data)->
        newModel = new TestModel(data)
        @add(newModel)
        newModel.save()
```

What am i doing wrong? I want to add the model to the collection after save()

Comment: Try [Collection.create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

Comment: @ivarni : Collection.create does it but i want to understand why doesn't model.save() work in my code.

Comment: You have to define `url` property for Model too. Collection's `url` is only responsible for fetching data.

Comment: @hindmost : By default model.url() is of the form "[collection.url]/[id]" http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url . Plus this still does not explain why its working when i add the model to the collection before calling save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `A "url" property or function must be specified` error because it fails on this [line](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L693)

Your last code works because model added to the collection has reference to `model.collection` so in this case `save` method can [resolve url](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L692). To get work your initial code you should provide `urlRoot` to your model like the following:

```
class TestModel extends Backbone.Model
   urlRoot: '/models'

initialize: ->
   return;

 module.exports = TestModel
```

According to [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot):

> Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model id. "[urlRoot]/id"